# Do gating mechanisms in the neocortex have individual degrees for all gated connections?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, computational-modeling

For example, the upward connection between layers in the neocortex flows through the thalamus which is assumed to have a gating function.

I wonder whether there is a single value per gate, determining the degree to which patterns can pass. Or can the gate be different for different synapses or signals at the same time? In this case, there would be more like a vector of degrees for all individual synapses of the gated nerve cord.

Is there anything known about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paper just came out last week in Neuron demonstrating dendrite-specific gating:
http://www.cell.com/neuron/fulltext/S0896-6273(16)00054-4?elsca1=etoc&elsca2=email&elsca3=0896-6273_20160302_89_5_&elsca4=Cell%20Press
Structured Dendritic Inhibition Supports Branch-Selective Integration in CA1 Pyramidal Cells
Erik B. Bloss, Mark S. Cembrowski, Bill Karsh, Jennifer Colonell, Richard D. Fetter, Nelson Spruston
DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.neuron.2016.01.029

Comment: After looking into the paper again, it seems like the paper only demonstrates dendrite-type-specific targeting. On other words, based on an activation pattern, most neurons that share a specific dendrite branch type get activated. But there is no targeting of individual neurons. Am I misinterpreting the paper? I'd be happy if you could comment on this.

Comment: presumably there are separate, cell-specific targeting mechanisms.  E.g. STDP

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any such work related on the thalamus?

Comment: no, i'd doubt it exists honestly.